# Java robot keypress "shift" on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, keypress, shift, awtrobot

I'm creating a automated typer using the built in Java robot class. I'm also building it on Mac and I've come across a fundamental flaw that is stumping me. No matter what,

> the "shift" key does not register.

I've tried `typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);` and a few key codes including `typerBot.keyPress(60);`

Ive looked all over the net and I can't find anything.

Here is a small sample program that replicates the problem I'm having on my machine:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class RobotClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {   //Gives you 5 seconds to click into a suitable environment for the robot to type
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String text = "AAAAAAAAAA";
        for(char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            RobotClass.typeChar(c);
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }

    }

    public static void typeChar(char c) {

        try {
            Robot typerBot = new Robot();
            switch(c) {
            case 'A':
                typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                typerBot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                typerBot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                break;
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {  e.printStackTrace();    }

    }

}
```

Input: `AAAAAAAAAA`

Output: `aaaaaaaaaa`

**My Question:** Why is the shift key not being recognized on mac?

Comment: Code would be nice - haven’t personally had the issue (lately)

Comment: I'm new to this site, so I'm not sure how to post code effectively, but here it is. I shortened it to 1 case so you can see whats going on.

public class RobotClass {

 public static Robot typerBot;
 
 public static void typeCharacter(char c) throws AWTException {
  typerBot = new Robot();
  
  char keyVal = c;
  typerBot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  switch(keyVal) {
   case 'A': typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); break;
   
  }
 }
 
}

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be thoughtful in how you apply key strokes, remember, you are "simulating" a physical user.

This means, in order to be able to type `A`, you need to press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then release <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (or at least release <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> when you're done)

The following is a really basic test that demonstrates the overall concept.  Open a text editor, run the program, you will have 5 seconds to get the editor into keyboard focus

```
Robot bot = new Robot();
bot.setAutoDelay(10);
Thread.sleep(5000);
Map<Character, Integer> mapStrokes = new HashMap<>();
mapStrokes.put('t', KeyEvent.VK_T);
mapStrokes.put('h', KeyEvent.VK_H);
mapStrokes.put('i', KeyEvent.VK_I);
mapStrokes.put('s', KeyEvent.VK_S);
mapStrokes.put(' ', KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
mapStrokes.put('e', KeyEvent.VK_E);
mapStrokes.put('a', KeyEvent.VK_A);
String text = "This is A test";
for (char value : text.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(value)) {
        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }
    int keyStroke = mapStrokes.get(Character.toLowerCase(value));
    System.out.println("Type " + value);
    bot.keyPress(keyStroke);
    bot.keyRelease(keyStroke);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(value)) {
        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Release your shift key and the pressed character at the end of the switch case or before the corresponding "break"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this also does not work. To be more specific in my debugging process(and how I narrowed it down to the shift key), I followed the following pattern:

The line I am trying to type is: AAAAAAAAAA
The line I'm editing in the code is: case 'A': typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); typerBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); typerBot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A); typerBot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); break;

The result is: aaaaaaaaaa